# Iterating through SPListItemCollection - why foreach is bad?

Tags: 2010, performance, best-practices, splistitemcollection

I have seen in different places that we should not use foreach to iterate through SPListItemCollection, but I can't find explanation, why?

E.g. http://de.slideshare.net/ghurlman/sharepoint-development-101/21

Bad:

```
foreach (SPListItem item in myList.Items)
{
  // loop
}
```

Good:

```
SPListItemsCollection items = myList.Items;
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
  // loop
}
```

But the code is really different, we can get items and use it with foreach as well

```
SPListItemsCollection items = myList.Items;
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
  // loop
}
```

Which one should I use and why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally speaking you will want to use SPQuery to only query items you're interested in.

Unless you're doing

```
SPList oList = web.GetList("XYZ");
for(int i=0; i < oList.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string strLstItemName = oList.Items[i].Name; // << BAD, as you use Items here, so you fetch them from DB each loop
}
```

there shouldn't be any relevant difference between your *bad* and *good* examples. It's not like foreach would fetch the whole Items collection from DB on each loop.

See Kobi's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965695/iterate-a-sharepoint-list). Also, I don't think generic .NET performance aspects play much of a role here as DB roundtrip is any way the slowest. Of course, with HUGE list you may end up waiting 60 secs for the data to arrive from DB to SharePoint, and THEN you can save 1 sec in using *for* loop instead of *foreach*.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you stick to the principle of storing the `SPListItemCollection` in a variable before looping through the items, the difference between using `for` instead of `foreach` is close to redundant.

The `foreach` loop will be converted into a `for` loop under the hood. It's a 1, perhaps 2 sec, difference.

So if you write:

```
var listItems = SPContext.Current.List.Items;
foreach (SPListItem item in listItems)
{
    Console.Write(item.Title);
}
```

Instead of:

```
var listItems = SPContext.Current.List.Items;
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.Count; i++)
{
    var item = listItems[i];
    Console.Write(item.Title);
}
```

Doesn't really make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of general c# comparistions between `for` and `foreach` - There is a [pretty comphrensive discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach) here

> 1. `for` loops on List are a bit more than 2 times cheaper than `foreach` loops on List.
> 2. Looping on array is around 2 times cheaper than looping on List.
> 3. As a consequence, looping on array using `for` is 5 times cheaper than looping on List using foreach (which I believe, is what we all do).

The source quoted in the above discussion - [here](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/11/19/an-easy-and-efficient-way-to-improve-net-code-performances/)

Comment: Thank you for general comparistions between for and foreach. But, I have read the main source and decided to make tests by myself, and, I have found no significant difference between for and foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Performance aside, there's a very compelling reason to use the `for` loop instead of `foreach`: Deletions. If you use a `foreach`--or even a `for` loop going forward (i.e. `for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)`)--you're going to end up, at best, skipping some items because the deletion will modify the collection as you're iterating through it. Thus, using a decrementing `for` loop is much better whenever modifying the collection's objects. Example:

```
SPListItemsCollection items = myList.Items;
for (int i = items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  SPListItem item = items[i];
  item.Delete();
}
```

This way, you don't end up pulling the rug out from under your feet.